# Calculating text width without losing DOM attributes

Tags: jquery

When trying to calculate text width using jquery, the "checked" attribute of the radio input is lost.
I am using the following code:

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
    var html_org = $(this).html();
    var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html_calc);
    var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
    $(this).html(html_org);
    return width;
};
```

I am calling it as follows:

```
$(".checkbox-inline-tooltip").each(function () {
     $(this).css({
         "position": "relative",
         "float": "left",
         "top": "-32px",
         "left": $(this).prev('label').textWidth() + 30 + "px"
     });
 })
```

The 'prev' label has a radio input. The attribute "checked" is lost after the textWidth() is called, which results in unchecking of the radio.

Comment: where is your html??

Comment: Please provide Snippet example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try element [**`wrapInner()`**](https://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) and [**`unwrap()`**](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). Getting the `innerHTML`, doesn't get the properties such as `checked, disabled` which are set dynamically in the input element.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(){
    $(this).wrapInner('<span>');
    var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
    $(this).find('span:first').contents().unwrap();
    return width;
};
```